# OS X, Cocoa: how can an app be signaled when a network connection becomes available?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I just noticed that [Textual](http://www.codeux.com/textual/) neatly reconnects me back to any IRC servers I have configured as soon as a network connection becomes available.

How can an application be signaled that a connection is up and running? I'm half-guessing/half-hoping the client isn't forced to constantly poll and is able to receive a signal/event instead.

How is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`SCNetworkReachability`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007260) class for this.